# Как заменить кнопку Login на Logout после захода на сайт?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, servlet

Всем привет, работаю сервлетами недавно, появился такой вопрос. После того как пользователь зашел на сайт, успешно "залогинился", мне нужно поменять кнопку `LOGIN` на `LOGOUT`. На данный момент я использую custom tag, для того, чтобы при успешном заходе на сайт, установить пользователю его имя, аватар и кнопку `LOGOUT`, но при этом я не знаю как удалить кнопку `LOGIN`. Что можете посоветовать?)

Мой customTag:

```
public class AvatarCustomTag extends SimpleTagSupport {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AvatarCustomTag.class);

    private String email;
    private String fName;

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    private String getFName(){
        return fName ;
    }

    private String getAvatar(){
        return "<img class=\"img\" src=\"avatar?email=" + email + "\"width=\"30\" height=\"30\">";
    }

    private String getLogout(){
        return "<a href=\"/logout\">LOGOUT</a>";
    }

    @Override
    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
        getJspContext().getOut().write(getFName() + getAvatar() + getLogout());
        LOG.debug("Avatar tag: " + fName + " " + email);
    }
}
```

Мой LogIn Servlet:

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LoginInfo loginInfo = new LoginInfo(req);

        if (userService.isExist(loginInfo.getEmail()) && userService.isLogin(loginInfo.getEmail(), loginInfo.getPassword())){
            req.getSession().setAttribute(FIELD_FIRST_NAME, userService.getByEmail(loginInfo.getEmail()).getFirstName());
            req.getSession().setAttribute(FIELD_EMAIL, userService.getByEmail(loginInfo.getEmail()).getEmail());
            req.getSession().setAttribute(SESSION_ROLE, userService.getByEmail(loginInfo.getEmail()).getRole());
            req.getRequestDispatcher(ConstantApp.JSPPages.INDEX_PAGE).forward(req, resp);
        } else if (!userService.isExist(loginInfo.getEmail())){
            req.setAttribute(ConstantApp.ErrorField.ERROR_EMAIL, ConstantApp.LoginField.ERROR_EMAIL_MESSAGE);
            req.setAttribute(ConstantApp.LoginField.ERROR_PASSWORD, ConstantApp.LoginField.ERROR_PASSWORD_MESSAGE);
            req.getRequestDispatcher(ConstantApp.JSPPages.LOGIN_PAGE).forward(req, resp);
        }
    }
}
```

Кусок кода главной страницы:

```
<div class="signin">
                  <div class="cart-sec">
                  <a href="cart.jsp"><img href="cart.jsp" src="images/cart.png" alt=""/>(0)</a></div>
                  <ul>
                     <li><c:if test = "${!empty sessionScope.email}">
                           <Avatar:avatar fName="${sessionScope.first_name}" email="${sessionScope.email}"/> <--Вставляю свой тэг -->
                     </c:if></li>
                     <li><a href="login.jsp"> LOGIN</a><span>/</span> &nbsp;</li> <--Данную кнопку надо заменить на LOGOUT или сделать, что то чтобы пока человек в сессии ее не было -->
                     <li><a href="registration">REGISTRATION</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
```

Comment: На главной странице с помощью `c:if test...`  организуйте проверку - если в сессии есть юзер, значит он уже залогинился и рисовать надо кнопку `LOGOUT`, иначе - `LOGIN`. Как-то так

Answer (score 0):

Логин и регистрация будет если пользователя нет в сессии, а тэг будет печатать линк для выхода.

```
 <c:if test = "${!empty essionScope.first_name && !empty sessionScope.email}">
       <li><Avatar:avatar fName="${sessionScope.first_name}" email="${sessionScope.email}"/></li>
 </c:if>
 <c:if test = "${empty sessionScope.first_name || empty sessionScope.email}">
       <li><a href="login.jsp"> LOGIN</a><span>/</span> &nbsp;</li> 
       <li><a href="registration">REGISTRATION</a></li>
 </c:if>
```